# JMeter - Calculate Time Difference

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have two time values captured via Regular Expressions. They are of the format given below:

```
Stop_Time     Start_Time
  11:05         11:08
  11:05         11:08
```

Now, the difference between these values are to be calculated and written to a file. I need to present the file in a below fashion:

```
Stop_Time     Start_Time   Duration
  11:05         11:08       3 mins
  11:05         11:08       3 mins
```

Please help.

Regards,
Ajith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the difference and store the result into a JMeter Variable using the following Groovy code:

```
def sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('HH:mm', Locale.ENGLISH)

def start = sdf.parse(vars.get('Start_Time'))
def end = sdf.parse(vars.get('Stop_Time'))

def delta = (end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / 1000 / 60

vars.put('Duration', delta as String)
```

Demo:

[image]

Then you can add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
sample_variables=Start_Time,Stop_Time,Duration
```

this way the variable values will be added to the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles). If you want to store the values in a separate file - take a look at [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin)

More information: [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)